# debian and ubuntu on the same machine

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, debian

How can I install debian and ubuntu on the same machine, I mean multi-boot, i've tried to install debian after ubuntu and there were grub problems, also I don't know can two "different" linux systems use same swap ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install debian first and then Ubuntu.So that the grub2 will be set as default bootloader.

Yes, both linux distros can be able to share a single swap.

Comment: Does it mean, that there's no need to create new swap area, when installing second OS ?

Comment: Yes, just make an entry for your swap partition in `/etc/fstab` file.

Comment: please say more detaily, thnx, how to make entry ?

Comment: After installing Ubuntu as second OS, it detects your swap partition and makes an entry automatically.If doesn't creates the entry for your swap partition then add this `UUID=5678-xxx-xxx none        swap    sw    0    0` line to `/etc/fstab` file.In this UUID represents your swap partition's UUID.Run `sudo blkid` command to see the UUID's of all your partitions.

Comment: If is this useful, then accept it.And also see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) for more about fstab.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it but don't forget to update the UUID of your swap partition in your first systme installed (in the /etc/fstab file) otherwise, your swap partition won't mount automatically at the boot for this one.

Comment: _don't forget to update the UUID of your swap partition in your first system_ this line means what?

Comment: I have made this experience. I have installed Ubuntu first and after Kali Linux with the swap partition shared. but after that, the swap partition was not mounted at boot on Ubuntu, the installation of Kali have changed the ID of the swap partition. so I have update the UUID of this partition in the Ubuntu /etc/fstab file to fix it.

Comment: it's nothing ^_^